# How to sum part of a matrix in Matlab without creating a submatrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, sum

So in Matlab, say I have a matrix X with size N by N, and i is an logical index vector with size 1 by N. Then I can do

```
sum(X(i,i))
```

The problem is it is equivalent to first allocating memory for

```
Y=X(i,i),
```

then computing the sum on Y, and deleting Y. Am I right? (Hoki's answer shows that it is right.)

Is there a faster way to compute the sum without (implicitly) creating Y? In case that Y is big, lots of time can be consumed in memory operations. In other words, is it possible to do something like the following:

```
S=zeros(1,nnz(i));

for k=find(i)
    for j=find(i)
        S(k)=S(k)+X(j,k);
    end
end
```

In this way, all the memory we need aside from X is a vector S - we don't need to allocate memory for the big Y. Of course, the loop can be slow, but you get my idea.

Comment: How do you know for sure that for your application, creating `Y` and summing over `Y` is going to be computationally intensive?  What tests, quantitative measures and/or justification do you have to make this conclusion?

Comment: Also, [JIT compilation](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=Matlab+JIT) likely comes into play.

Comment: I don't think I made a conclusion. I suggested it and asked if I was right. I want to see if someone has experience with it. So to answer your comments, I am simply not absolutely sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assume too much on how memory management is operated.

**Timing:**

I ran a benchmark with timeit. From N=10 to N=20000 there is absolutely **no noticeable difference** in the execution time of both forms.

Moreover, I still get the very same results if I turn the JIT acceleration off ... so the optimization may be just the result of Matlab `lazy-copy` behaviour.

**Memory usage:**

On the memory side, there seem to be a difference though. The indirect method (with the temporary variable) seem to **allocate the memory for this temporary variable** (The size allocated correspond exactly to the size of the temporary variable). On the other hand, the direct method does not need any extra memory allocation to return a result.

This reaches the limits of my grasp on these things. I am not expert enough to pretend to explain why this difference in memory usage does not result in a timing difference. I know memory is fast but for high order of `N` I thought it would have made a difference. Apparently not ...

**More info:**

For more details on Matlab memory management, I invite you to read this article from Loren at Matlab:
[Memory Management for Functions and Variables](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/)

or if you want to read a more in-depth testing of the mechanism:
[Internal Matlab memory optimizations](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/internal-matlab-memory-optimizations)

---

### Time benchmark:

Benchmark result:

[image: exectime]

Benchmark code:

```
function ExecTimes = benchmark_sumcol

%// prepare logarithmic progression (up to what my 16GB RAM can take)
nOrder = (1:9).' * 10.^(1:3) ; nOrder = [nOrder(:) ; 10000 ; 20000] ; %'
npt = numel(nOrder) ;

ExecTimes = zeros( npt , 2 ) ;

for k = 1:npt
    %// Sample data
    N = nOrder(k) ;
    X = rand(N) ;
    ci = logical(randi([0 1],1,N)) ;

    %// Benchmark
    f1 = @() direct_sum(X,ci) ;
    f2 = @() indirect_sum(X,ci) ;
    ExecTimes(k,1) = timeit( f1 ) ;
    ExecTimes(k,2) = timeit( f2 ) ;

    clear X ci
    disp(N)
end

function R = direct_sum(X,ci)
R = sum(X(:,ci)) ;

function R = indirect_sum(X,ci)
Y = X(:,ci) ;
R = sum(Y) ;
```

---

### Memory benchmark:

- Summary for both functions

[image: both]

- Detail for indirect summation, with temporary variable. I highlighted the memory allocation:

[image: both]

- Detail for direct summation:

[image: both]

Code for memory benchmark

```
%% // set profiler options
clear all
profile('-memory','on');
setpref('profiler','showJitLines',1);
profile on

%% // sample data
N = 1000 ;
X = rand(N) ;
ci = logical(randi([0 1],1,N)) ;

%% // Benchmark
R2 = bench_indirect_sum(X,ci) ;
R1 = bench_direct_sum(X,ci) ;

%% // result
profile viewer
p = profile('info');
profsave(p,'profile_results')
```

---

### Last Edit:

I added your `loop` version to the tests, although I had to rework it a bit to make it actually work (and give the same results than the others):

```
function R = bench_loop_sum(X,ci)
    R = zeros(1,nnz(ci));
    idxRes=1 ;
    for k=find(ci)
         for j=1:size(X,1)
             R(idxRes)=R(idxRes)+X(j,k);
         end
        idxRes = idxRes+1 ;
    end
```

The result is ok in terms of memory (that is no extra memory allocation for a temporary array), but is catastrophic in terms of speed:
[image: loopjiton]

And as we could expect with loops, even worse with the JIT off:
[image: loopjitoff]

---

Now a simple change to suppress the inner loop makes things a lot better, but still a bit behind the direct way (note that this version **do not** allocate memory for a temporary column to do the sum):

```
function R = bench_loop_sum(X,ci)
    R = zeros(1,nnz(ci));
    idxRes=1 ;
    for k=find(ci)
        R(idxRes) = sum(X(:,k));
        idxRes = idxRes+1 ;
    end
```

[image: loopshortjiton]
*with the JIT on.*

Comment: Doesn't your benchmark test prove exactly what I guessed: Matlab does direct sum by creating a submatrix (allocating memory) first then operate on the submatrix? Let me change my question and see if you see what I actually meant.

Comment: Forgot to say I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @maxwell, you're right ... or so I thought. Then I ran memory profiling on both options and I found differences there ... although I can't really explain why the timing is identical.

Comment: Let me mark your answer the accepted one, though we are still not sure how to speed up a partial sum by removing the redundant step of creating a temporary matrix. I would blame the mysterious Matlab rather than us.

Comment: @maxwell. Well, what I draw from these tests is that the direct way **does not** create a temporary matrix. So it is still a good solution if you have to limit memory usage. Unfortunately, it does not seem to provide any speed up ...

Comment: Right, from the memory profiling results, it does not. But from the time consumed, it seems to do... Anyways...

Comment: @maxwell ... i added a loop version to the test. Apparently the one liner without temporary variable is still the best contender.

Comment: @Hoki Thanks. Guess sum(X(i,i)) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers , if you will always be looking for complete columns, the answer is simple

```
t=sum(X);
```

is a row with the sum of all the columns

then

```
ans=sum(t(i))
```

is what you want.

if you might be looking for odd shapes linear indices might be what you are looking for.

See
[sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)

First create a linear index into the matrix (a 1D indexing) then use that index directly

usage sum over six items (5 through 10) in columns i

```
ind = sub2ind(size(X) , ones(6,1)* i , (5:10)'*ones(1,N))  ; 
sum(X(ind))
```

Comment: Hmmm I am not sure that solves the problem at hand. First i is not a scalar, second you still create X(ind) in memory.

Comment: ok, got you, revised answer. r=sum(t) is a row with the column sums. res=sum(r(i))

Comment: Good pt. but let's say we want to calculate sum(X(i . i))

Comment: X(i,i) is a square submatrix of X.